# Filtering with query_post by postID

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the following sentence for querying some Post:

```
query_posts('post_type=page&posts_per_page=2&meta_key=category_news&meta_value=ht_news&lang=en');
```

The question is that I need to be able to prevent such query get in its result a certain postID, so how can i add such code?

In normal SQL query it could be `WHERE postID NOT IN (12, 120, 150)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exclude` to *exclude* the PostID that you specify in your query.

```
query_posts('
     post_type=page
     &posts_per_page=2 
     &meta_key=category_news
     &meta_value=ht_news
     &lang=en
     &exclude=1,2,3,4,5'
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but WP_Query has the `post__not_in` argument that you can use.

Arguments of WP_Query from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
p (int) - use post id.
name (string) - use post slug.
page_id (int) - use page id.
pagename (string) - use page slug.
post_parent (int) - use page id. Return just the child Pages.
post__in (array) - use post ids. Specify posts to retrieve.
post__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve.
```

You can have a look at this question of [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/17305) to get more information on which type of query you need. [Rarst answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/17305) is probably the best explanation I've seen about the three ways to query posts in Wordpress.